# ¿Cómo configurar el botón "close" creado para una ventana, para que al momento de presionarlo se me permita volver a abrir la ventana?

Tags: java, javafx

Deshabilité el header de la ventana para así jugar con la estética: para esto es necesario crear los botones de salir y ocultar. Los botones dentro de la ventana están creados desde el Controlador de la misma, pero el Stage de esta ventana se genera en el Dashboard Controller.

Creé el evento con su respectivo método para el botón cerrar en la ventana desde su controlador de la siguiente manera:

```java
private void closeWindow() {

        Stage stage = (Stage) btnClose.getScene().getWindow(); 
        stage.close();
}
```

Entonces en el Dashboard abro la ventana, con el botón recientemente creado me permite cerrarla, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero al momento de volver a abrir la ventana en el Dashboard (que fue anteriormente cerrada) ya no me abre. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: si el Button  btnclose  está en  ese stage  ; la instancia del controlador ya no está disponible al cerrar stage.  El orden es stage>>scene>>Parent   btnClose está dentro de parent